# Print The Formula

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

### Introduction

In chemistry there is a type of extension, .xyz extension,(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format), that prints in each line
a chemical element, and the coordinates in the plane of the element. This is very useful for chemists to understand chemical compounds and to visualize the compounds in 3D. I thought it would be **fun** to, given a .xyz file, print the chemical formula.

### Challenge

Given an .xyz file, print the chemical formula of the compound in **any** programming language in the smallest possible number of **bytes**. Note:

- Originally, the input was to be given as a file. As I have been pointed out, this constraints the challenge. Therefore **you may assume** the input is a list/array of strings, each representing a line of the .xyz file.
- There are no restrictions in the ordering of the elements.
- Each element should be printed with an underscore "_" delimiting the element and the number of times it appears
- The first two lines of any .xyz file is the number of elements, and a comment line (keep that in mind).

### Example Input and Output

Suppose you have a file *p.xyz* which contains the following (where the first line is the number of elements, and the second a comment), input:

```
5  
A mystery chemical formula...  
Ba      0.000   0.000  0.000  
Hf      0.5     0.5    0.5  
O       0.5     0.5    0.000  
O       0.5     0.000  0.5  
O       0.000   0.5    0.5
```

---

> **Output:**
>   Ba_1Hf_1O_3

---

### Testing

A quick test is with the example mentioned. A more thorough test is the following:
since the test file is thousands of lines, I'll share the .xyz file:
https://gist.github.com/nachonavarro/1e95cb8bbbc644af3c44

Comment: Requiring input to be read from a file unnecessarily and unfairly prohibits a very significant portion of programming languages from participating in your challenge. See: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/3808, http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/3808

Comment: @Doorknob Good point. I've changed that.

Comment: Code golf, code challenge, and fastest code are mutually-exclusive tags. The score should be in bytes, not characters. The file format should be completely described in the question, instead of requiring outside resources. Use a [GitHub Gist](http://gist.github.com) instead of an untrusted file hosting service. Because of these issues, I'm voting to close as unclear. Please use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) in the future.

Comment: @Mego how about now? :)

Comment: @nacho There are still many issues with it. You should probably delete this question, post it in the Sandbox, and then post it to main after getting feedback and fixing issues that others point out.

Comment: what is the answer for the large test case?

Comment: Does ordering matter in the output?

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 18 bytes

```
sjL\__MrShMcR;ttQ8
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sjL%5C__MrShMcR%3BttQ8&input=%5B%275++%27%2C+%27A+mystery+chemical+formula...++%27%2C+%27Ba++++++0.000+++0.000++0.000++%27%2C+%27Hf++++++0.5+++++0.5++++0.5++%27%2C+%27O+++++++0.5+++++0.5++++0.000++%27%2C+%27O+++++++0.5+++++0.000++0.5++%27%2C+%27O+++++++0.000+++0.5++++0.5++%27%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 21 bytes

```
U=¢m¸mg)â £X+'_+Uè_¥X
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VT2ibbhtZyniIKNYKydfK1XoX6VY&input=WwoiNSIKIkEgbXlzdGVyeSBjaGVtaWNhbCBmb3JtdWxhLi4uIgoiQmEgICAgICAwLjAwMCAgIDAuMDAwICAwLjAwMCIKIkhmICAgICAgMC41ICAgICAwLjUgICAgMC41IgoiTyAgICAgICAwLjUgICAgIDAuNSAgICAwLjAwMCIKIk8gICAgICAgMC41ICAgICAwLjAwMCAgMC41IgoiTyAgICAgICAwLjAwMCAgIDAuNSAgICAwLjUiCl0=) Input is given as an array of strings (which can be formatted as in the link).

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
U=¢   m¸  mg)â £    X+'_+Uè_  ¥ X
U=Us2 mqS mg)â mXYZ{X+'_+UèZ{Z==X

          // Implicit: U = input array of strings
Us2       // Slice off the first two items of U.
mqS mg    // Map each item by splitting at spaces, then taking the first item.
U=    )   // Set U to the result.
â mXYZ{   // Uniquify, then map each item X to:
UèZ{Z==X  //  Count the number of items Z in U where Z == X.
X+'_+     //  Prepend X and an underscore.
          // Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 44

```
NR>2{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)printf i"_"a[i]}
```

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/7RPZ0s)

Answer (score 0):

## Shell + GNU Utilities, 67

```
sed '1d;2d;s/ .*//'|sort|uniq -c|sed -Ez 's/\s*(\S+) (\S+)/\2_\1/g'
```

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/InlBTt)

Comment: `1d;2d` → `1,2d`

Comment: Just because trailing spaces in the output are not forbidden: `tail -n+3|cut -c-3|sort|uniq -c|sed -rz 's/\s*(\S+) (\S+)/\2_\1/g'`

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>79</s> 53 bytes

```
StringRiffle[Tally@StringExtract[#[[3;;]],1],"","_"]&
```

Quite simple.